# How to connect 1 table with another 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `t1`, `t2`, `t3`. Each one has `ID` and `name` columns. In `t2`, and `t3`, the field name is inserted after adding `www.`. What I need to do is: select all records from `t1` that are not in `t2` or `t3`.

I could retrieve the required records from `t1` and `t2`, and then another similar query for `t1` and `t3`. What I need to do is to make this in one statement.

The following statement to retrieve the names that are in `t2` but not in `t1`:

```
select t1.name
from db.t1
LEFT JOIN db.t2 ON 
t2.name = concat('www.',t1.name) 
WHERE t2.name IS NULL;
```

A similar one is done to retrieve records from t1 and t3. How to make this in one statement ?

Answer (score 2):

try it by using `UNION`

```
select  t1.name
from    db.t1
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT name FROM t2
            UNION 
            SELECT name FROM t3
        )   t ON t.name = concat('www.',t1.name) 
WHERE t2.name IS NULL;
```

or by using `LEFT JOIN` (*still*)

```
select  t1.name
from    db.t1
        LEFT JOIN db.t2 
            ON  t2.name = concat('www.',t1.name) 
        LEFT JOIN db.t3 
            ON  t3.name = concat('www.',t1.name) 
WHERE t2.name IS NULL AND 
        t3.name IS NULL;
```

Comment: @kmb385 I'll go for two `LEFT JOIN`. I just showed the OP the different ways to achieve what he desired. :D

Comment: Thanks for answering, BTW I'm not the original poster. +1 for the explanation, even though I have a horse in the race :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another join

```
select t1.name
from db.t1
LEFT JOIN db.t2 ON 
t2.name = concat('www.',t1.name) 
LEFT JOIN db.t3 ON 
t3.name = concat('www.',t1.name) 
WHERE t2.name IS NULL and t3.name IS NULL;
```